# Cannot create LUKS encrypted partition: passwords do not match

Tags: partition, manjaro, luks

I use Manjaro Architect 19.0
I've created `ext4` partition `/dev/sda2` with `parted`

Then I go to luks encryption, select my partition and choose "automatic luks format". It asks for passphrase twice. If I enter password containing a backslash `\` symbol followed by a letter, for example, `\a` then it says that my passwords do not match. Is it possible to enter such a combination?

UPD:
If type `\a` on first step and `\\a` on the second then it works. But how my password actually looks now? `\a` or `\\a`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in the source code of installer. To compare passwords the following expression is used now:

```
[[ $PASSWD != $PASSWD2 ]]
```

It fails with my given examples. If change to:

```
[[ "$PASSWD" != "$PASSWD2" ]]
```

It will work. I will report this case to devs of Manjaro